# IOException when trying to access SD card from android

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-sdcard

everyone. I'm trying to save a picture with android to the public pictures directory on the sd card. However, I can't seem to get as far as opening a file for writing. Here is the code:

```
                boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

               mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            } 

            if(mExternalStorageWriteable){
                    File root_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    root_dir.mkdirs();
                    File pictures_directory = new File(root_dir, "/Pictures/");
                    pictures_directory.mkdirs();
                    File outputfile = new File(pictures_directory, "test_file.jpg");
                    try {
                        outputfile.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
```

My debugger always jumps to the catch block (caused by the createNewFile call) and the IOExceptions message is "Not a Directory". If I remove the createNewFile call, the FileOutPutStream constructor will throw a FileNotFound exception. Opening a fileoutput stream to the root of the file system or the pictures directory seems to work fine however.

To dispense with the obvious, my manifest includes the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> tag. I'm using API level 5 and my emulator has a virtual SD card mounted to it. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

SOLVED: There was a problem with the emulator filesystem. DDMS showed /Pictures/ being created as a file or a directory for some reason. Creating a new emulator solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's usually a bad manner to hard coder path separators. Try just `Pictures` instead of `/Pictures/`. The last one is an absolute path which point to a folder in root:

```
File pictures_directory = new File(root_dir, "Pictures");
```

UPD:

I have compiled and run your code snippet with no problems. So the problem is in your emulator file system. Try to remove that Pictures file first, or even create a new sdcard image for your emulator.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I don't really think that's the problem anyway because, as mentioned, I can successfully open a FileOutputStream to the Pictures directory. Another piece of potentially useful information is that my debugger shows the pictures_directory path as "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures"

Comment: @Colin That's weird. I have compiled and run your code snippet with no problems. So I guess the problem is in your emulator file system. Try to remove that Pictures file first, or even create a new sdcard image for your emulator.

Comment: Your hypothesis appears to be correct. I have tested it with a fresh emulator and everything runs fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Colin updated the answer with the solution, so it would be easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusing the following two methods:

`File(String Path)` and `File(File dir, String name)`

As such, pictures_directory should be a directory not a complete path + filename.

Try changing

```
File pictures_directory = new File(root_dir, "/Pictures/");
```

to

```
File pictures_directory = new File(root_dir + "/Pictures/");
```

Comment: Tried it but no dice. I'm not sure the java File library makes much distinction between a directory and an individual file does it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Make sure you have test_file.jpg in your res/drawable directory.

```
    private void writeToSDCard() {
    try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        if (root.canWrite()){
            InputStream from = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.test_file);
            File dir = new java.io.File (root, "Pictures");
            dir.mkdir();
            File writeTo = new File(root, "Pictures/test_file.jpg");
            FileOutputStream  to = new FileOutputStream(writeTo);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = from.read(buffer)) != -1)
                to.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); // write
            to.close();             
            from.close();
        } else {
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Unable to access SD card.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "writeToSDCard: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}   "
```

Comment: I tried it, but I still got an exception the moment it tried to create it hit FileOutputStream(writeTo). Here is the exact detail message of the FileNotFoundException: "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/test_file.jpg (Not a directory)".

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Eclipse. Can you go to the DDMS perspective (screen) and look at File Explorer and see if the Pictures directory is being created. Is this on the emulator or an actual device? If it's on the emulator, did you create an sd card when you created the AVD (in the Android SDK and AVD Manager).

Comment: Your correct in your assumption. There is a Pictures file under the /mnt/sdcard directory, but it doesn't look like a folder, it just shows as a file. Other stats: size is 0, permissions are ----rwxr-x. One other possibly useful fact is that it's present before it even enters the function. I'm assuming the system creates it. PS: I'm testing on a virtual device (Android 2.2), and it does have an SD card mounted.